# Retornar a diferença de dados de duas tabelas sql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma tabela `ESCOLA` com `ID_ESCOLA` e `NOME_ESCOLA` e outra tabela `PROFESSORES` que contem um `FK_ID_ESCOLA` e `NOME_PROFESSOR`. Eu queria uma tabela que me retornasse o nome de todas as escolas porém as escolas que não tivessem nenhum professor retornasse com uma outra cor. Eu sei como tratar esses dados, só não sei como montar o [sql](/questions/tagged/sql).

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
SELECT Escola.nome_escola, count(Professores.ID)
FROM Escolas
LEFT JOIN Professores
ON Escolas.ID_ESCOLA=Professores.FK_ID_ESCOLA
GROUP BY Escolas.ID_ESCOLA;
```

Answer (score 2):

Faça um `COUNT` nos professores pra saber quando tem e quando não tem, exemplo:

```
SELECT e.nome_escola, COUNT(p.nome_professor) qtdeProfessores
FROM ESCOLA e
LEFT JOIN PROFESSORES p ON p.ID_ESCOLA = e.ID_ESCOLA
GROUP BY e.nome_escola
```

Dessa forma quando vier `qtdeProfessores` = 0, então tu mostra uma cor, quando vier <> 0 mostra de outra.